# $\lim_{N \rightarrow \infty}\dfrac{1}{N^d}|E \cap \dfrac{1}{N}\mathbb{Z^d}|$ may not exist

Tags: analysis

In [this](https://terrytao.wordpress.com/2010/09/04/245a-prologue-the-problem-of-measure/) page, under Remark $1$, the limit 
$$\lim_{N \rightarrow \infty}\dfrac{1}{N^d}|E \cap \dfrac{1}{N}\mathbb{Z^d}|$$ may not exist.

Question: For $d=1$, that is, in $\mathbb{R}$, what is the example of $E$ such that the limit does not exist? I try but to no avail.

Can anyone give some hint?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint**: Consider the set $E = \left\{x \in (0,1) : x = \dfrac{m}{2^n} \ \text{for some} \ m,n \in \mathbb{Z}\right\}$.

Try to show that $\dfrac{1}{2^k}\left|E \cap \dfrac{1}{2^k}\mathbb{Z}\right| \to 1$ as $k \to \infty$, but $\dfrac{1}{2^k+1}\left|E \cap \dfrac{1}{2^k+1}\mathbb{Z}\right| \to 0$ as $k \to \infty$.

Remark: This easily generalizes to higher dimensions $d$.

Comment: Thanks. May I know the motivation of getting this example?

Comment: Just want to check with you, $|E \cap \dfrac{1}{2^k}\mathbb{Z}|=2^k-1$ while $|E \cap \dfrac{1}{2^k+1}\mathbb{Z}|=0$, am I right?

Comment: ^That's what I got as well. The motivation was that $|E \cap \tfrac{1}{N}\mathbb{Z}|$ counts the number of points in $E$ that are of the form $\tfrac{m}{N}$ for some integer $m$. So, if $E$ contains only rational numbers in $(0,1)$ whose denominators are in "some special form", then $\tfrac{1}{N}|E \cap \tfrac{1}{N}\mathbb{Z}|$ will be small for some integers $N$ and larger for other values of $N$. If $\tfrac{1}{N}|E \cap \tfrac{1}{N}\mathbb{Z}|$ hits large and small values infinitely often, then the limit won't exist. By playing around a bit, I came up with that example.